# Firefox corrupting video card, persists through reboot

Tags: firefox, graphics-card, video

My Firefox seems to be corrupting my video card. When I use Firefox the screen develops snow, then after a little while, it goes entirely beige (never seen that before), the computer seems to still be operating (drive lights are normal etc), but the screen is non-operative, just beige.

If I restart I get snow on the "checking disk" page, then eventually it beiges it out, even if I do not start Firefox.

If I restart a SECOND time, then the computer seems fine (as long as I don't start Firefox).

Currrently I am using Chrome to write this question. Chrome seems completely fine. I can watch videos etc.

I am interested in finding out why this is happening. Please don't just write "reinstall Firefox". I know that. That is not helpful. I want to understand WHY this happening and what Firefox could be doing that it is corrupting the video card.

Comment: Disable Hardware/GPU acceleration in Firefox and see if it helps.

Comment: Which operating system are you running? Try updating the video card device driver.

Answer (score 0):

As I should have suspected, the presence of flickering snow indicated a hardware problem: the video card was bad.

The question is why Firefox should trigger the meltdown, but not Chrome.

After using Chrome for a long period of time, the same problem occurred.

Thus, apparently the explanation is that Firefox, for whatever reason, possibly hardware acceleration features, was driving the card harder than Chrome so it was failing sooner.

The bottom line here is that if you see snow, it is probably the video card.